# Why can't I reset my persistent store's contents?

Tags: ios, core-data

My app stores a lot of data for the current user in a Core Data persistent store. If the user logs out, I want to drop all this data and start over.

Right now, my code looks like:

```
NSError *error;
[_managedObjectContext lock];
[_managedObjectContext reset];
[_persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:_persistentStore error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[_persistentStore URL] error:&error];
    // error handling here
_persistentStore = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self _storeURL] options:nil error:&error];
[_managedObjectContext unlock];
```

But no matter what I do, the next time I perform a fetch request I get all the old data back. I've verified that the actual file is being deleted off the filesystem, so apparently this data is coming from memory somewhere. I've tried the above code, I've tried resetting the managed object context to nil and starting over from the very beginning, but none of the changes appear to take place until I terminate the app and re-run it.

EDIT: Actually, not even terminating the app does anything. I see the sqlite file disappear from the folder it's in after the `NSFileManager` line, and then on the line where I add a new persistent store, it recreates an exact copy of the old one.

EDIT: Okay, I turned on Core Data debugging. As soon as I call `removePersistentStore:` I see "Disconnected from sqlite database." The very next line, `addPersistentStoreWithType:`, I see a ton of `INSERT` statements which I guess is magically restoring the contents of the database from memory? Can I get it to... not do that?

EDIT: Well, for now I've just gone with manually deleting the contents of the data store by looping through my managed objects. This works, somehow. Fortunately for this project, users only have up to a couple hundred objects so it's not terribly time consuming, but I still wish I understood what was happening...

Comment: I assume you don't get any errors in the above code? You might also turn on core data debugging to see the SQL being executed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a Core Data debugging option. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Tear down the entire stack, and then remove the file.  If you are using UIManagedDocument, then you have a file package.  Make sure you close the document, and then remove the entire file package.

Comment: I tried doing it in that order just now but it made no difference. I'm not using UIManagedDocument.

Comment: I called `removePersistentStore:`, then set the persistent store, persistent store coordinator, managed object model, and managed object context to `nil`, then I deleted the sqlite file, then I instantiated everything again. Then I logged myself back in as a different user but I still see all the data from the previous user. I literally stepped through all of this line by line and watched the file get deleted in my Finder window :/

Answer (score 0):

I was worried about this for a project we're working on, so I've made a test, but I can't make it show the behaviour you're seeing. This is all in the simulator with iOS 5.1.

I just tried the following code in Apple's default core data template with a model with a single entity "Entity" with a string property called "name". The code inserts an entity, saves the context, removes the store, deletes the store file and then re-adds the store. The objects are present before removing the store and absent afterwards, as expected. (I've also tried adding the managedObject lock/reset/unlock, with the same results.)

So, there must be something else going on. Can you try to make a reduced test-case like this?

```
NSManagedObject *object = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
                                   insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[object setValue:@"hi" forKey:@"name"];
NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];

NSLog(@"before: %@", [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]);


if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:[[self.persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores] lastObject]
                                                      error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataTest.sqlite"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}

if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeURL
                                                    options:nil
                                                           error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}

NSLog(@"after: %@", [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]);
```

Comment: The same thing happens. I had a second managed object context at one point when I was doing some fetching in the background, but I eventually decided it wasn't worth it. That code isn't even in my project anymore.

Comment: @AnshuChimala I've added some more notes; basically, I can't reproduce what you're seeing, so I suspect there's something else going on.

Comment: Another thing you might try is putting a breakpoint on, say, sqlite functions and seeing what code is causing your rows to be inserted. If you have a stack trace for one of those insertions, you could post it.